# ArrayList of Hashsets !! Compilation error

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, hashset, set

I'm writing a java program for joining sets. This is just a small portion of my code where I keep getting a compilation error.

```
ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>(n+1);

for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
{
        list.add(i, new HashSet<Integer>());
        list.get(i).add(i);
}

if(list.get(a).contains(a)  && list.get(b).contains(b))
{
        Iterator it = list.get(b).iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            **list.get(a).add((int)it.next());**       //Compilation Error!
        }
        list.get(b).clear();
}
```

Is there an easier way perform the join? Thank you :) !!

Comment: I have no error (Except a and b that are not declared here). what IDE do you use?

Comment: If you get a compiler error, post the compiler error. The details.

Comment: inconvertible types found : java.lang.Object required: int list.get(a).add(new Integer((int)it.next()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing the line with

```
list.get(a).add((Integer)it.next());
```

Comment: cannot find symbol symbol : constructor Integer(java.lang.Object) location: class java.lang.Integer list.get(a).add(new  Integer(it.next()));

Comment: @vsaijan4 yes, sorry try casting the Object to int like a do in the edited answer

Comment: It works fine on my system. But its showing an error on the server where I'm trying to submit :(

Comment: @vsaijan4 please give me the error so that I can help you

Comment: inconvertible types found : java.lang.Object required: int list.get(a).add(new Integer((int)it.next())); This was the error.

Comment: @vsaijan4 OK now I see what the problem is. Simply replace the line with: `list.get(a).add((Integer)it.next());` An object can be cast to Integer but not to int.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. BTW why was my post downvoted :(. I'm new here.

Comment: @vsaijan4 people here like to see short and self-contained questions. What is missing here is that you did not post the error you got, just pointed out ther is an error and so we must guess. Also maybe some users decided that you could have solved your problem on your own had you trying googling. I did not downvote the question btw, but also got downvotes on my answer

Comment: Oh! OK. Will try to provide enough detail next time. Thanks a lot :). I tried googling - "Arraylist of Hashsets". I never found a proper website which explained how to use it. All the results I kept getting were "ArrayList is better or HashSet" :(. I have a lot of questions to post now ;) !! Thanks again :) !

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

```
    Iterator it = list.get(b).iterator();
```

with

```
    Iterator<Integer> it = list.get(b).iterator();
```